# How to run hello-world in Contiki OS?

Tags: c, contiki

I am new to contiki os, I tried to compile and run hello-world.c file located in examples directory in contiki os 3.0. But I got the error,

> hello-world.c:40:21: fatal error: contiki.h: No such file or directory".

I tried this in root user.

[image]

Any kind of help to run very beginner program in contiki is appreciated.

Comment: It's better to just copy the text from the terminal to the post instead of taking a picture.

Comment: Thank you for posting image. Image is far more better to know the exact error. so tried to post image. From next time i will post the error from terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `make` command to build Contiki. Doing that invokes architecture-specific version of `gcc` with compiler flags pointing to the the proper header file paths:

By default, `make` is going to build for the "native" platform (that is, `x86`) and create an application image that is executable on the host PC.

To build for a specific hardware platform, set the `TARGET` variable. For example, to build for Tmote Sky/TelosB nodes:

```
make TARGET=sky hello-world
```

To build and run for the native platform:

```
make
```

Output:

```
TARGET not defined, using target 'native'
mkdir obj_native
...
CC        hello-world.c
LD        hello-world.native
rm hello-world.co
```

To run it:

```
./hello-world.native
```

Output:

```
 Contiki-3.x-1457-g552408b started with IPV6, RPL
 Rime started with address 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8
 MAC nullmac RDC nullrdc NETWORK sicslowpan
 Tentative link-local IPv6 address fe80:0000:0000:0000:0302:0304:0506:0708
 Hello, world
```

Comment: I am very new to contiki. so i could not run the hello-world . could you please provide me some more detail about the way to run the hello-world. I would appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, who helped to answer my question. Finally, I am able to run first hello-world program in Contiki OS. I have use the following code syntax.

```
$cd contiki
$cd examples/hello-world
$make TARGET=native
```

To run the compiled code use the following code.

```
$ ./hello-world.native
```

Out put:

```
Contiki 3.0 started with IPV6, RPL
Rime started with address 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8
MAC nullmac RDC nullrdc NETWORK sicslowpan
Tentative link-local IPv6 address fe80:0000:0000:0000:0302:0304:0506:0708
Hello, world
```